# Reorder a Django query after slice

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Is there a way to reorder a Django query after a slice has been taken?

I am trying to do the following, but I get this error: `Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.`

**models.py:**

```
class PhotoManager(models.Manager):
    def most_commented(self):
        return super(PhotoManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
            the_count=(Count('comment'))).order_by('-the_count')[:100]
```

**views.py:**

```
def home(request):
    most_commented = Photo.objects.most_commented()
    photos = most_commented.order_by('?')

    context = {
        'photos': photos
    }
return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

My goal is to take the top 100 most commented on pictures and then randomize the order they are displayed in.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939035/django-reorder-queryset-after-slicing-it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert photos to list and then shuffle normally:

```
import random

...

def home(request):
    most_commented = Photo.objects.most_commented()
    photos = list(most_commented)
    random.shuffle(photos)
    context = {
        'photos': photos
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: I can't accept the answer yet, but I will when I can. Thank you for the help!